# Get Rails Date Select Form Helper to display on a single line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a form_for helper with the bootstrap framework. When I use date_select it creates a dropdown box for the year, month and date but they're all on separate lines. I was wondering if there was any way of getting them all to display on the same line? My current CSS for forms looks like this:

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

In response to a comment here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span8 offset2">
      <%=form_for(@service) do|f|%>

         <%=f.label :date, "Date" %>
         <%=f.date_select :date, id: "dateField" %


         <%=f.submit "Add to Rota", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post your html source code?

Comment: @WawaLoo That's the html source code added

Comment: I was talking of the HTML source code from your browser, not the view code. So that we can take a look at the elements, classes and ids.

Comment: In any case the answer worked so thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @FantasticMrK , could you post your final solution? The one proposed just puts every field "glued" to each other, and the "-" and ":" separators on the right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
float: left;
width: 150px;
```

The width has to be fixed with float left to make elements "follow" each other.

Answer (score 1):

Wawa Loo answer is ok, but it still gave me some headaches find out the final solution to line up my fields just with the "-" and the ":" on the right place, so i post my answer here too.

Here is my campaigns css file (I have begin and end dates, where i wish to set the datetime):

```
#campaign_startdatetime_1i,#campaign_enddatetime_1i{
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 5px;

}
#campaign_startdatetime_2i,#campaign_enddatetime_2i{
  width: 150px;
}
#campaign_startdatetime_3i,#campaign_startdatetime_4i,#campaign_startdatetime_5i,
#campaign_enddatetime_3i,#campaign_enddatetime_4i,#campaign_enddatetime_5i{
  width: 75px;
}
```

As you will notice, i only put the float:left on the first input, since if i apply it to all "select" boxes, than the "-" that splites date and time and the ":" would just appear out of place.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to add one of Bootstrap grid classes to the html output, like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, {}, { :class => "col-md-4" } %>
```

Since "col-md-4" is set to use up a third of the parent column width, that would leave you with all three fields in a single line I believe.